# Android Bootstrap not displaying icons in button

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap

I implemented Android Bootstrap library:
https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap

Everything works fine, but icons in buttons are not displayed.

I add font-awesome file into asset folder, but still without successful result.

How can be this solved?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is Android Bootstrap the same as Twitter Bootstrap? Or only inspired by it? I'm referring to the tag.

Comment: Did you check my answer, I had the same problem and by copying the `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` font into the `asset` folder of project, it worked.

Comment: I have answered the solution under another topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566199/1719066

Answer (score 1):

Try what it worked for me, make sure that "android-support-v4.jar" file in libs folder (assuming that you're working in eclipse) is the same copy in AndroidBootstrap library project and your project. 
This might only partially solve your problem, you might have problems with the icon not displaying when you change orientation (landscape/portrait) and there might be better solution, but this is my quick fix:

in OnResume add:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){

        bbYourButton1.setLeftIcon("fa-heart");
        bbYourButton2.setRightIcon("fa-twitter");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem loading the font, you should get the reason in the log cat, as we can see in   [com / beardedhen / androidbootstrap / BootstrapButton.java](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/blob/master/AndroidBootstrap/src/com/beardedhen/androidbootstrap/BootstrapButton.java)   at line 343

```
 Log.e("BootstrapButton", "Could not get typeface because " + e.getMessage());
```

So, go to the logcat and see if you can understand what happened.

Anyways, the better start point is to import the [AndroidBootstrapTest](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/tree/master/AndroidBootstrapTest) project and see if everything works.

Comment: I check that, no exception is throw. If i tried to rename font file, exception has been thrown. So it looks that everythong is o.k, but icon is still not displayed.

Comment: I found, that in layout preview in Android Studio is now displayed warning message:
Typeface.createFromAsset() is not supported.

Comment: So i tried to add icons on the left and there are working.

Maybe some issue with Android Studio combination

Answer (score 0):

Just copy `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` into `assets` folder of your project.