# Android Bootstrap by Bearded-Hen Icons Fonts not showing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-typeface, android-bootstrap-widgets

I just downloaded the sample from [Android-Bootstrap](https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap), But all the fonts Icons are not displaying.

I just downloaded the latest version, and still I am having the same problem. (I tried to run the sample project) also same issue.

Is anyone have this issue ? or does anyone knows how to came around ?

Answer (score 1):

[fontawesome-webfont.ttf](http://fontawesome.io/assets/font-awesome-4.7.0.zip) file download and copy to app/src/main/assets. In the OnCreate event of the application, add the following code. 
 `TypefaceProvider.registerDefaultIconSets();`

Comment: I did that but still not working. Font awesome icons are not working. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The fontawesome icons will only display if `fontawesome-webfont.ttf` is present in the assets folder of your app, so you need to copy the file there. In a typical Android studio project your assets folder can be found at `app/src/main/assets`.